# Outputting file list with linebreaks to Microsoft Teams

Tags: rest, powershell, microsoft-teams

we are trying to get a file-list with certain filtering to our technical support department on Microsoft Teams.

Technically it works, but the output is messed up. For some reason it is not possible for me to get the files as a list to Teams. Instead, all files are just pasted in one large string with spaces between the filenames.

I've tried some formatting options, but couldn't get anywhere closer to a solution.

```
$Limit = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)
$Path = "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop"
$Extension = "*.*"

$Results = @()
$Results += Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Extension -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $Limit -and ! $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Extension -ne ".db"} | Select-Object Name -ExpandProperty Name | Sort-Object Name

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType "Application/Json" -Body "{'text': '$Results'}" -Uri https://outlook.office.com/webhook/<deleted for this example...> | Out-Null
```

What I would like to get in Teams : a list with one filename per line
What I get now in Teams : One long string with filenames separated with a space.

Thank you in advance for any help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a line break to each item in the array which in Teams I believe is 3 spaces and \n

That would look like this:

```
$Limit = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)
$Path = "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop"
$Extension = "*.*"

$Results = @()
$Results += Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Extension -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $Limit -and ! $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Extension -ne ".db"} | Select-Object Name -ExpandProperty Name | Sort-Object Name
$Results = $Results | Foreach-Object {"$_   \n"}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType "Application/Json" -Body "{'text': '$Results'}" -Uri https://outlook.office.com/webhook/<deleted for this example...> | Out-Null
```

If that doesn't work you may need to Loop through your array and add `<br>` to the end of each object but you will need to add `<pre></pre>` to apply HTML formatting.

That looks like this: (I tested this with `Send-MailMessage -BodyAsHtml` worked flawlessly)

```
$Limit = (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)
$Path = "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop"
$Extension = "*.*"

$Results = @()
$Results += Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Filter $Extension -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt $Limit -and ! $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Extension -ne ".db"} | Select-Object Name -ExpandProperty Name | Sort-Object Name
$Results = $Results | Foreach-Object {"$_<br>"}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType "Application/Json" -Body "{'text': '<pre>$Results</pre>'}" -Uri https://outlook.office.com/webhook/<deleted for this example...> | Out-Null
```

Let me know if any of these work out for you!

Answer (score 0):

the first solution you've posted was the correct one !
Thank you so much for your quick help. I've tried similar options with
**`n**, but Teams did not accept that as a valid line break.

I owe you a cold pint of beer :-)
Sincerely,
Ruud

Comment: Awesome sir! Glad it worked out for you, if you could please vote my answer as the correct one so if anyone else has the problem they quickly find the solution! Cheers, a cold pint sounds good right about now ;)